# What port do crypted websockets use?

Tags: ssl, https, websocket

What port is used for `wss:` requests?

Does it change anything to do a request since a HTTP or a HTTPS page?

Are crypted websockets able to do a HTTPS handshake?

Comment: This is really trivial information to find on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websockets use HTTP, so port 80 or 443 for encrypted communications.